# Partially Identical Hands in Hold'em

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, random

I was playing Texas Hold'em at a local cardroom last night keeping a meticulous record of the hands I was dealt.  Perhaps I am totally wrong but I thought the occurrences of certain events in this poker session were considerably outside the realm of statistical expectancy but, although I took statistics in college, I am having trouble computing some probabilities.  Can someone please help me?

This poker session lasted 4 hours 10 minutes and consisted of 142 hands.

In the course of these 142 hands, there were 38 instances of two (2) consecutively dealt hands in which the latter hand contained at least one card of the same rank as one of the cards in the prior hand.  This seemed to me to be a high percentage (26.76%) of such events in a session of this length and consisting of this number of hands.

Could someone please tell me the probability of two consecutively dealt hands containing at least one card of identical rank (**not** rank *and* suit) and how this is calculated?

Additionally, there were three (3) instances of two (2) consecutively dealt hands in which both cards in the latter hand contained were the exact same rank (**not** rank *and* suit) as the first hand.

Same question as for the 38 instances?

I know that, relatively speaking, this is a very small sample of poker hands.  However, is it probable that this could happen if the player is receiving "random hands"?

To anyone who chooses to help me with this I ***really*** appreciate your time.

Comment: It’s fun to do such experiments! Just a small warning. It is extremely easy to bias yourself (towards “this was outside the realm of statistics”) in such an analysis by just searching through the dataset for abnormal incidences without taking into account the so-called [look-elsewhere effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-elsewhere_effect). You are bound to find something strange if you just search through enough things. One way to avoid this bias is to decide beforehand what you are going to study [how many pairs do I get, how many flushes, …] or do a proper analysis (much harder).

Answer (score 4):

The number of ways of choosing $2$ cards out of $52$ twice is $\binom{52}2^2=1758276$. The number of ways of doing it such that the cards don't share any ranks is

$$
\binom{13}{4}\cdot\frac{4!}{2!^2}\cdot4^4+2\cdot13\cdot\binom42\cdot\binom{12}2\cdot4^2+13\cdot12\cdot\binom42^2=1268592\;.
$$

The three terms represent the three possibilities that $0$, $1$ or $2$ of the hands are pairs. If there are no pairs, we can choose $4$ of $13$ ranks; their $4!$ different permutations are distinct up to two factors of $2!$ for permuting within each hand; and each rank can independently be from one of $4$ suits. If there is one pair, it can be in one of two hands and have one of $13$ ranks, and we can choose $2$ of $4$ suits for it, which leaves $12$ ranks to choose the two ranks in the other hand from, and again $4$ suits for each of those two cards. If there are two pairs, we can choose one of $13$ ranks for the first and one of $12$ for the second, and for each pair we can again choose $2$ of $4$ suits.

Thus the probability for successive deals not to share a rank is

$$
\frac{1268592}{1758276}=\frac{8132}{11271}\approx72\%\;,
$$

so the probability that they do share a rank is about $28\%$, so your observed value of $38$ is very slightly below the expected value of $141\cdot\frac{8132}{11271}\approx39.3$.

The second question is a bit easier. Of the $\binom{52}2$ deals, there are $\binom{13}2$ rank doublets that each occur $4^2=16$ times and $13$ rank singlets (pairs) that each occur $\binom42=6$ times. Thus the probability for the rank signatures to coincide is

$$
\frac{\binom{13}2\cdot16^2+13\cdot6^2}{\binom{52}2^2}=\frac{20436}{1758276}=\frac{131}{11271}\approx1.2\%\;,
$$

so in this case you did see a substantially above-average number of occurrences, $3$ compared to the expected value $141\cdot\frac{131}{11271}\approx1.6$. The probability of observing $3$ successes in $141$ Bernoulli trials with $p=\frac{131}{11271}$ is $\binom{141}3p^3(1-p)^{138}\approx14\%$. This isn't quite the probability for your observation, a) because you would have been at least as surprised if there had been even more such coincidences, and b) because the $141$ trials aren't fully independent because pair hands differ from unpaired hands. Both effects should be quite small, though. (Note that this affects only the last result, the probability; the expectation values are exact since the [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity) doesn't require independence.)

Comment: I do know one thing for an absolute certainty. There is no way and it is mathematically impossible by far to get 1,758,276 unique two-card combinations out of the standard deck of 52 cards. It tops out at 1326 even with both rank and suit considered.  Accordingly, I question an reject this answer in its entirety.

Comment: Also please see my comments at the "duplicate" question:  Question re Hold'em Hands with Identical Ranks [duplicate]

Comment: @FrankGuest: I suggest you keep away from Q&A sites if you're so certain of what you think you know and have so little interest in what others know. Also please see my comments at [the duplicate question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1401657).

Comment: Whatever little imaginative role you are playing on this site, if you enjoy it and others buy off on it -- go for it.  Have fun!  But you can't change the statistical law that says the number of unique combinations of 2 from a sample of 52 unique objects is (52 X 51)/2.  It will always be that no matter what hi-faluting theorems are considered.  It's as basic as 2+2=4, the speed of light in a vacuum is 186,000 mps, and true intellects don't attempt to change basic constants because they may have misused or misquoted one;

Comment: I would respectfully suggest that you get out of mathematics and develop a strong interest in philosophy.

Comment: Wow what an attitude by OP! This answer is correct. If unsure this can be checked very easily on a computer (draw random cards and count how many times the conditions are met). This takes no time and gives exactly the same result in both cases.